# Webdriverio element functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriver-io

I posted the original question here:

https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/394

But i'd figure to post here as well for more visibility.

I've been struggling with using the `element` functionality and am always getting an error like the following:

```
{
message: 'RuntimeError\n(UnknownError: 13)Anunknownserver-sideerroroccurredwhileprocessingthecommand.\nProblem: eisnull\nBuildinfo: version: \'2.44.0\',
revision: \'76d78cf\',
time: \'2014-10-2320: 02: 37\'\nSysteminfo: host: \'hella.home\',
ip: \'192.168.1.6\',
os.name: \'MacOSX\',
os.arch: \'x86_64\',
os.version: \'10.10.1\',
java.version": \'1.7.0_55\'\nDriverinfo: driver.version: unknown\u001b[
    1;30m\n\nCallstack: \n->element(".my-class-name")\n',
    name: 'RuntimeError',
    hasCallStack: true
}
```

Even when using an id value or a regular tag name, i get a similar error message. This is what some of the code looks like i'm trying to test:

```
client
    .url('https://example.com/')
    .element('.my-class-name',function (err, result) {
        console.log(err, result);
    })
    .call(done);
```

The `client` is setup similar to the [mocha/chai/jasmine examples](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/examples) and I am seeing my other code run so  that configuration I'm not concerned about.

thoughts?

Comment: have you tried adding `waitForExist('.my-class-name')` before `element`?

Comment: @Dziamid this turned out to be some wrapper I have going on with the client stuff so it's not an issue in the library.